# getting 'API resource location is not registered' error with Azure pipeline cache task

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to cache my npm dependencies using the Cache task in Azure Pipelines. I'm using Azure DevOps Server 2020. When the pipeline runs I get the following error message:

```
Resolving key:
 - npm                          [string]
 - "Windows_NT"                 [string]
 - Web/package-lock.json [file] --> 118CDFE1CFD866ABF2489C955D015ED5D2962A76602B6B544D996C46B84
Resolved to: npm|"Windows_NT"|1C9oHznmI3rlvpEvjwhi+Ssx/V05b9WttZRq
Resolving restore key:
 - npm          [string]
 - "Windows_NT" [string]
Resolved to: npm|"Windows_NT"|**
Information, Getting a pipeline cache artifact with the following fingerprint: `npm|"Windows_NT"|1C9oHznmI3rlvpEvjwhi+Ssx/V05b9WttZRqxHYD+2w=`.
##[error]API resource location a7c78d38-31a8-417e-ba6b-7e58b352f304 is not registered on https://[azure_devops_url]/DefaultCollection/.
```

Here is part of my pipeline YAML:

```
variables:
    npm_config_cache: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/Web/.npm
steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: 'Use Node 14.15.0'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 14.15.0
      checkLatest: false
  - task: Cache@2
    displayName: 'Cache NPM packages'
    inputs:
      key: 'npm | "$(Agent.OS)" | Web/package-lock.json'
      restoreKeys: |
        npm | "$(Agent.OS)"
      path: $(npm_config_cache)
  - script: npm ci
```

I install my npm packages in a subfolder. How do I solve the error?

Comment: You're using private agents; packages are implicitly cached as long as you don't clean the working folder between builds. This feature is really intended primarily for the hosted agent in Azure DevOps Cloud, where there is nothing persisted between builds.

Comment: My packages are not cached between builds. The nodejs install gets cached.

Comment: I checked the Microsoft documentation. Caching of npm packages is done with the cache task. I don't clean the working folder between builds and the pipeline installs the npm packages every time. I need the cache task but it doesn't work in DevOps Server 2020.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks that this is not supported on premises. Please check this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13937).

Comment: Unbelievable. Microsoft clearly states the Cache task is available in Azure DevOps Server 2020 but doesn't actually work.

Comment: This is strange indeed. Issue is fresh (18 days ago), so I doubt that someone stated wrong answer there. Possibly a bug in documentation. @mdailey77 Can you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful for you?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm frustrated with Microsoft. This isn't the first time where their documentation says a feature is available in a specific version of DevOps Server when it actually isn't.

Comment: This is literally the third feature that is documented as working in DevOps Server 2020 on the official docs that I tried to use this week and found out it is not supported and the docs are incorrect.

The fact that it's not supported is frustrating enough, but the fact the docs lead you on a wild task goose chase is insanity.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely not supported on On-Premises. BTW, also neither is the MS DevLabs solution [azure-pipelines-artifact-caching-tasks](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-artifact-caching-tasks) You can use the solution provided here, which is based on Powershell scripts. It works very well: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-artifact-caching-tasks/issues/41#issuecomment-863395122